# error TS2494: Using a string in a 'for...of' statement is only supported in ECMAScript 5 and higher

Tags: typescript

when I use a string in the for..of construct to loop through the letters, typescript throws an error. Why? How can I fix it? Here's an example to reproduce:

forOf.ts

```js
for (let letter of 'string') {
  console.log(letter);
}
```

```sh
➜  ch5_HOF tsc forOf.ts 
forOf.ts:1:20 - error TS2494: Using a string in a 'for...of' statement is only supported in ECMAScript 5 and higher.

1 for (let letter of 'string') {
                     ~~~~~~~~


Found 1 error.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is typescript compiles your code to [ES3 by default](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html), which doesn't support for..of with a string, so you need to specify a compiler target that does, for example:

```sh
➜  ch5_HOF tsc --target es6 forOf.ts
➜  ch5_HOF
```

This compiles without error, and here is what the compiled javascript looks like:

forOf.js

```js
for (let letter of 'string') {
    console.log(letter);
}
```