# Typescript: Using a string in a 'for...of' statement is only supported in ECMAScript 5 and higher

Tags: typescript

Whenever I try to loop through a JSON file, I get `Using a string in a 'for...of' statement is only supported in ECMAScript 5 and higher.`
I have tried this solution [error TS2494: Using a string in a 'for...of' statement is only supported in ECMAScript 5 and higher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58944447/error-ts2494-using-a-string-in-a-for-of-statement-is-only-supported-in-ecma)
but it I get this errr after doing `tsc --target es6 forOf.ts`: `error TS6053: File 'forOf.ts not found. The file is in the program because: Root file specified for compilation`

What do I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

Go to your `tsconfig.json`
In that change `target`: `es6`

And run `tsc` in your cmd/terminal in root directory

Comment: Doesn't work =(

Comment: Can you send ss of your folder structure and file that you are trying to execute

Comment: What is an ss though?

Comment: Screenshot of your folder structure, so that I can try and see why is it not working

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/ujwzYFV

Comment: That is a bit awkward but I actually have just fixed it =))

Comment: Haha Happens, welcome to programming :)